# How to get the TF-IDF of a certain word from a certain date?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

is it possible to calculate the tf-idf metric of a certain word from a certain date with python pandas?

I want to display the tf-idf metric for the word **dog** using the dates **2008-01-02** and **2008-01-05**.

```
index  date         comment                                                  age
0      2008-01-02   I love dogs, I think dogs are the best.                  22
1      2008-01-03   I can't have cats because of my allergy. I like cats.    19
2      2008-01-04   This is awesome.                                         25
3      2008-01-05   I want a dog.                                            35
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use an NLP library like gensim. You can follow the first example at [TF-IDF](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.html) page.

You'd basically want to use your 'comment' column as your corpus and then you can calculate the TF-IDF for each row in that column.

```
from gensim.models import TfidfModel
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary

doc_list = []
for comment in df['comment']:
    doc_list.append(comment)
dct = Dictionary(doc_list)
corpus = [dct.doc2bow(line) for comment in df['comment']]
model = TfidfModel(corpus)
```

Then you can iterate through your corpus and find the TF-IDF values. There may be some inaccuracies in this code since I can't test for a while but the general idea should work :) .